# They launched a scheme for people to apply for leave to remain through an app

Tags: sentence-meaning

I don't know what's wrong with me or BBC, but I often need double-takes in order to understand some sentences within news articles coming from BBC.

This time no matter how many takes, [I don't understand this sentence](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-46950719):

> The government launched a pilot scheme this week for people to apply for leave to remain through a smartphone app.

I just cannot break down the meaning of this.

Here are some sentences I could come up with :

> A smartphone app will remain available for people to apply for [work] leave.

or

> A smartphone app will remain available for people planning to leave the country to apply on.

or

> The government left the remaining task to a smartphone app, where people can apply for.

None of these sentences make sense in the context of the article (if they even made any sense at all); So what does this sentence mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "leave to remain" is a single, technical term in UK immigration Law. It is the status of someone who has been allowed to stay in the UK for the next 5 years.

> The government launched a pilot scheme

Pilot means a test of the scheme. When did the goverment launch it?

> this week,

What is the scheme for?

> for people to apply...

What will they apply for?

> for "leave to remain"

How can people apply for this?

> through a smartphone app.

The context is people from EU countries may have to apply for "Leave to Remain" when the UK leaves the EU

Comment: It is not surprising that the phrase 'leave to remain' might puzzle someone. It is as @JamesK says a technical term but it originates in the use of the word 'leave' as, now an old-fashioned, synonym for 'permission'. One can be given leave to do, or not do something, without having to move away.